# Mangento2 : Use default loader for all process

Tags: magento2

Magento2 use loader for specific portion which are being updating.
i.e `minicart section`,`product image section`,`estimate shipping`.
I want show default loader in page.
How can I do that?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What is the loader which you're talking about? Can you give me info?

Comment: loader is shown at differnt position http://prntscr.com/jfyybo , http://prntscr.com/jfyyqh I want it in centr which is default http://prntscr.com/jfyykg something like `jQuery('body').loader('show');` and `jQuery('body').loader('show');` instead multiple

Comment: I think should keep the default loader, this is because it will show for a part which is updating data.

Comment: I know that but I want to do what I mentioned,thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Very close to Solution**
I have tried this solution but it is not working on checkout due to multiple ajax loader is there so any of them is conflict.I have use Amasty Checkout

I have oveeride `module-ui\view\base\web\js\block-loader.js` and use `$('body').loader('show');` and `$('body').loader('hide');` and remove it's template file but some time loader not hide in checkout page due to multiple ajax call on that page,also product gallery loader is not affected with this code.I don't know it is proper metjhod or not?

```
define([
    'ko',
    'jquery',
    'mage/template',
], function (ko, $, template) {
    'use strict';

    var blockLoaderTemplatePath = 'ui/block-loader',
        blockContentLoadingClass = '_block-content-loading',
        blockLoader,
        blockLoaderClass,
        loaderImageHref;

     blockLoader = $(blockLoader);

    /**
     * Helper function to check if blockContentLoading class should be applied.
     * @param {Object} element
     * @returns {Boolean}
     */
    function isLoadingClassRequired(element) {
        var position = element.css('position');

        if (position === 'absolute' || position === 'fixed') {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Add loader to block.
     * @param {Object} element
     */
    function addBlockLoader(element) {
       $('body').loader('show');
    }

    /**
     * Remove loader from block.
     * @param {Object} element
     */
    function removeBlockLoader(element) {
       $('body').loader('hide'); 
    }

    return function (loaderHref) {
        loaderImageHref = loaderHref;
        ko.bindingHandlers.blockLoader = {
            /**
             * Process loader for block
             * @param {String} element
             * @param {Boolean} displayBlockLoader
             */
            update: function (element, displayBlockLoader) {
                element = $(element);

                if (ko.unwrap(displayBlockLoader())) {
                    addBlockLoader(element);
                } else {
                    removeBlockLoader(element);
                }
            }
        };
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, This is default by magento 2

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_loader.html